# How can I extract text between parentheses containing a specific word?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I convert this:

```
foo (blah) (bar 80)
foo (cats) (blat 92)
```

To this:

```
foo bar 80
foo blat 92
```

I would like to keep all the text that is NOT in parentheses.

I only want to extract text between parentheses that contain the strings "bar" or "blat" in them.

Pairs of parentheses that do not contain "blat" or "bar" should be ignored.

Sed or awk will be much preferred

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to keep _all_ text that is not in parentheses and, of the strings in parentheses, keep only those that start with `blat` or `bar`? What if `blat` or `bar` is somewhere else in the parenthesis? Can there be spaces between the parentheses and the strings?

Comment: Yes terdon, I would like to keep all the text that is NOT in parentheses. Pairs of parentheses that do not contain `blat` or `bar` should be ignored. They do not have to start with `blat` or `bar` as long as they are inside the parentheses, and yes a space is preferred between the parentheses and the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is indeed possible in `sed` or `awk`, it is much easier (for me, anyway) using Perl:

```
$ perl -ple '@pars=( /(\(.+?\))/g ); 
              for $par (@pars){
                s/\s*.$par.// unless $par=~/blat|bar/
              } s/[()]//g;' file
foo bar 80
foo blat 92
```

#### Explanation

- `-ple` : `p`rint each line of the input file, after `e`xecuting the script on it. The `-l` removes trailing newlines and adds a newline to each call of `print`.
- `@pars=( /(\(.+?\))/g );` : the `@pars` array now contains all strings that are within parentheses.
- `for $par (@pars){ ... }` : for each of the strings found above.
- `s/\s*.$par.// unless $par=~/blat|bar/` : remove this set of parentheses if they don't contain `blat` or `bar`.
- `s/[()]//g;` : Remove all parentheses (not the text within them).

You could also <del>golf</del> condense the above to

```
perl -ple 'for$par((/(\(.+?\))/g)){$par=~/blat|bar/||s/\s*.$par.//};s/[()]//g;' file
```

Comment: Great answer and very well explained.
Was Perl preferred because the question is a little too complex for sed/awk to do?

Comment: @user264974 Perl was preferred first and foremost because I prefer Perl, so it's much easier for me. That said, yes,  while you could play around with the hold space and try to match the different strings in sed, that would make for a very long and cryptic sed command. Awk would be even worse since it really is not designed for this kind of thing. It wants its data in columns.

Comment: @user264974 I take that back. I hadn't realized that `sed` can deal with non-grouping parentheses but [apparently](http://askubuntu.com/a/616357/85695) it can.

Answer (score 5):

Using `sed`:

```
< inputfile sed 's/(\([^\)]*\(bar\|blat\)[^\)]*\))/\1/g; s/(.*) //g'
```

Input file:

```
test (bar) (blat)
bar (testblat) (bartest)
blat (testbar) (barblat) (no) (blatanother)
```

Output file:

```
test bar blat
bar testblat bartest
blat testbar barblat blatanother
```

**Breakdown**:

#1:

- `(`: matches a `(` character
- `\(`: starts grouping the capturing group
- `[^\)]*`: matches 0 or more characters not `)`
- `\(`: starts grouping the allowed strings
- `bar`: matches the 1st allowed string
- `\|`: separates the 2nd allowed string
- `blat`: matches the 2nd allowed string
- `\)`: stops grouping the allowed strings
- `[^\)]*`: matches 0 or more characters not `)`
- `\)`: stops grouping the capturing group
- `)`: matches a `)` character

#2:

- `(`: matches a `(` character
- `.*`: matches 0 or more characters
- `)`: matches a `)` character
- : matches a  character

Comment: @terdon I didn't understood he wanted to remove non-matching pairs of parenthesis as well, thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Using `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pat_list = re.findall(r'\(([^)]*?)\)', line.rstrip())
        for pat in pat_list:
            if not re.search(r'(?:blat|bar)', pat):
                print re.sub(r'\(|\)', '', line.replace(' ({0})'.format(pat), '').rstrip())
```

**Output:**

```
foo bar 80
foo blat 92
```

- Here we have used the `re` (Regular Expression) module of `python`.
- `pat_list` will contain the list of strings within parentheses
- Then we have searched for the presence of "blat" or "bar" in the `pat_list` members
- If not found, we have printed the line removing unnecessary portionss including parentheses.

Comment: @TuxForLife: Thanks..yeah..i am interested..i will mail you..lets remove the comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:
Save the following code into a text file and make it executable (`chmod u+x filename`).

Then, run it like this:

```
awk -f filename inputfile
```

This is huge compared to solutions in `perl` or `python`, I'm adding this just because `awk` or `sed` was the preferred solution and to show that it's possible to use `awk` even though it's not convenient.

```
{
#list of words to look for in parentheses: (named "w" to speed up adding items)
w[0] = "bar";
w[1] = "blat";

#"bool" value whether of not to crop spaces around omitted parenthesis with their content
cropSpaces = 1;

spaces = 0;                     #space counter used for cropping 
open = 0;                       #open/nested parenthesis counter
st = 0;                         #marks index where parenthesis starts
end = 0;                        #marks index where parenthesis ends
out = 0;                        #"bool" value indicating whether or not the word has been found
for(i = 1;i-1 < length($0);i++){     #for each character
  c = substr($0,i,1);                 #get character
  if(c == "("){                       #character is '('
    open++;                            #increment parenthesis counter
    if(open == 1) st = i+1;            #marks start of parenthesis (if not nested)
  }
  else if(c == ")"){                 #char is ')'
    open--;                           #decrement parenthesis counter
    if(open == 0) end = i;            #mark end of parenthesis (if not nested)
  }
  else{                             #any other char
    if(open == 0){                   #outside of parenthesis
      if(cropSpaces && c == " "){     #char is space (and cropSpaces option is not 0) 
        if(spaces == 0) printf c;      #print space if not sequential  
        spaces++;                      #increment space counter
      }
      else{                           #any other char
        spaces = 0;                    #set previous spaces counter to 0
        printf c;                      #print char
      }
    }
    else if(!out){                   #inside of parenthesis (and no word has been found)
      for(j = 0; j < length(w); j++){               #for every word in list
        if( substr( $0,i,length(w[j]) ) == w[j]){    #if word matches
          out = 1;                                    #word has been found
          break;                                      #do not look for any other words
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(open == 0 && out){              #outside of parenthesis and word found in previous parenthesis
    printf substr($0,st,end-st);      #print content
    out = 0;                          #reset "word found" indicator 
    spaces = 0;                       #reset spaces counter
  }
}

printf "\n";                        #print newline
}
```

Comment: I do not see any output.

Comment: @A.B. the awk call was wrong, you need awk -f to run the script. Try the updated version.

Comment: Works and +1 for the effort. Where you learn that? ;)

Comment: @A.B. Oh, my bad, sorry for wrong command...  I'm studying informatics on CTU in Prague and `awk` scripting was part of obligatory "Programming in Shell 1" course (in first semester).

Comment: I can see why perl/python is preferred in this situation. That is quite the code, thank you for the grand effort. Kos' sed solution is really short, I actually expected awk to be shorter

Comment: @user264974 It's possible there is a shorter way to do this using `awk` maybe it's just that I'm not that good with `awk` :) Still you can do anything with `awk` because it runs any code you want for all lines matching specified format - that's why I like it.

Answer (score 0):

little late but, what about this, power of oneline simplicity:

```
> cat test.py
from string import replace

stuff = '''
foo (blah) (bar 80)
foo (cats) (blat 92)
'''

for i in stuff.split('\n'):  # split by \n
  if i != str():  # not empty string
    print ''.join(i.split()[0]+' '+i.split()[2]+' '+i.split()[3]).replace('(','').replace(')','')

>>> python test.py 
foo bar 80
foo blat 92
```